# AWS Ampify console preview build from a forked branch

Tags: aws-amplify

We have an app in AWS Amplify that has previews enabled for it.

Devs fork our github repo, create a branch in that fork and issue a pull request from that forked branch into the upstream master branch.  This doesn't trigger the preview build in Amplify.  Has anyone tried this?

It seems to work fine with PR from a branch within the repo, but not a forked version.  The other wrinkle is that we have other checks/webhooks that run on PR as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is not supported at the moment, but there is a GitHub issue tracking the feature request: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-console/issues/508

We mainly use a fork / PR workflow, so this would be a big help for us too.

Comment: When you have more reputation you'll be able to use the comment feature. This is more of a comment than it is an answer to the question. Leaving this here as an answer will cause fewer people to see this as a question without an answer and may hinder it getting a good answer.